# Get latest child per parent from big table - query is too slow

Tags: sql, django, performance, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a query generated by Django's ORM, that is taking hours to run.

The `report_rank` table (50 million rows) is in a one to many relation to `report_profile` (100k rows). I'm trying to retrieve the latest `report_rank` for each `report_profile`.

I'm running Postgres 9.1 on an extra large Amazon EC2 server with plenty of available RAM (2GB/15GB used). Disk IO is pretty bad of course.

I have indexes on `report_rank.created` as well as on all foreign key fields.

What can I do to speed this query up? I'd be happy to try a different approach with the query if it will be performant, or to tune any database configuration parameters needed.

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT "report_rank"."id", "report_rank"."keyword_id", "report_rank"."site_id"
     , "report_rank"."rank", "report_rank"."url", "report_rank"."competition"
     , "report_rank"."source", "report_rank"."country", "report_rank"."created"
     , MAX(T7."created") AS "max" 
FROM "report_rank" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "report_site" 
  ON ("report_rank"."site_id" = "report_site"."id") 
INNER JOIN "report_profile" 
  ON ("report_site"."id" = "report_profile"."site_id") 
INNER JOIN "crm_client" 
  ON ("report_profile"."client_id" = "crm_client"."id") 
INNER JOIN "auth_user" 
  ON ("crm_client"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "report_rank" T7 
  ON ("report_site"."id" = T7."site_id") 
WHERE ("auth_user"."is_active" = True  AND "crm_client"."is_deleted" = False ) 
GROUP BY "report_rank"."id", "report_rank"."keyword_id", "report_rank"."site_id"
     , "report_rank"."rank", "report_rank"."url", "report_rank"."competition"
     , "report_rank"."source", "report_rank"."country", "report_rank"."created" 
HAVING MAX(T7."created") =  "report_rank"."created";
```

Output of `EXPLAIN`:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1136244292.46..1276589375.47 rows=48133327 width=72)
  Filter: (max(t7.created) = report_rank.created)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1136244292.46..1147889577.16 rows=4658113881 width=72)
        Sort Key: report_rank.id, report_rank.keyword_id, report_rank.site_id, report_rank.rank, report_rank.url, report_rank.competition, report_rank.source, report_rank.country, report_rank.created
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1323766.36..6107863.59 rows=4658113881 width=72)
              Hash Cond: (report_rank.site_id = report_site.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on report_rank  (cost=0.00..1076119.27 rows=48133327 width=64)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1312601.51..1312601.51 rows=893188 width=16)
                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=47050.38..1312601.51 rows=893188 width=16)
                          Hash Cond: (t7.site_id = report_site.id)
                          ->  Seq Scan on report_rank t7  (cost=0.00..1076119.27 rows=48133327 width=12)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=46692.28..46692.28 rows=28648 width=8)
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2201.98..46692.28 rows=28648 width=8)
                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=2201.98..5733.23 rows=28648 width=4)
                                            Hash Cond: (crm_client.user_id = auth_user.id)
                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=2040.73..5006.71 rows=44606 width=8)
                                                  Hash Cond: (report_profile.client_id = crm_client.id)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on report_profile  (cost=0.00..1706.09 rows=93009 width=8)
                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1761.98..1761.98 rows=22300 width=8)
                                                        ->  Seq Scan on crm_client  (cost=0.00..1761.98 rows=22300 width=8)
                                                              Filter: (NOT is_deleted)
                                            ->  Hash  (cost=126.85..126.85 rows=2752 width=4)
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on auth_user  (cost=0.00..126.85 rows=2752 width=4)
                                                        Filter: is_active
                                      ->  Index Scan using report_site_pkey on report_site  (cost=0.00..1.42 rows=1 width=4)
                                            Index Cond: (id = report_profile.site_id)
```

Answer (score 7):

The major point is most likely that you `JOIN` and `GROUP` over everything just to get `max(created)`. Get this value separately.

You mentioned all the indexes that are needed here: on `report_rank.created` and on the foreign keys. You are doing alright there. (If you are interested in better than "alright", *keep reading*!)

The `LEFT JOIN report_site` will be forced to a plain `JOIN` by the `WHERE` clause. I substituted a plain `JOIN`. I also simplified your syntax a lot.

**Updated July 2015** with simpler, faster queries and smarter functions.

#### Solution for multiple rows

`report_rank.created` is **not unique** and you want **all** the latest rows.
Using the window function [`rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a subquery.

```
SELECT r.id, r.keyword_id, r.site_id
     , r.rank, r.url, r.competition
     , r.source, r.country, r.created  -- same as "max"
FROM  (
   SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY created DESC NULLS LAST) AS rnk
   FROM   report_rank r
   WHERE  EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM   report_site    s
      JOIN   report_profile p ON p.site_id = s.id
      JOIN   crm_client     c ON c.id      = p.client_id
      JOIN   auth_user      u ON u.id      = c.user_id
      WHERE  s.id = r.site_id
      AND    u.is_active
      AND    c.is_deleted = FALSE
      )
   ) sub
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Why `DESC NULLS LAST`?

- [Why do NULL values come first when ordering DESC in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958679/why-do-null-values-come-first-when-ordering-desc-in-a-postgresql-query/20959470#20959470)

#### Solution for one row

If `report_rank.created` is **unique** or you are satisfied with **any 1 row** with `max(created)`:

```
SELECT id, keyword_id, site_id
     , rank, url, competition
     , source, country, created  -- same as "max"
FROM   report_rank r
WHERE  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   report_site    s
    JOIN   report_profile p ON p.site_id = s.id
    JOIN   crm_client     c ON c.id      = p.client_id
    JOIN   auth_user      u ON u.id      = c.user_id
    WHERE  s.id = r.site_id
    AND    u.is_active
    AND    c.is_deleted = FALSE
   )
-- AND  r.created > f_report_rank_cap()
ORDER  BY r.created DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  1;
```

Should be faster, still. More options:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

### Ultimate Speed with dynamically adjusted partial index

You may have noticed the commented part in the last query:

```
AND  r.created > f_report_rank_cap()
```

You mentioned 50 mio. rows, that's a lot. Here is a way to speed things up:

- Create a simple `IMMUTABLE` function returning a timestamp that's guaranteed to be older than rows of interest while being as young as possible.
- Create a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) on younger rows only - based on this function.
- Use a `WHERE` condition in queries that matches the index condition.
- Create another function that updates these objects to the latest row with dynamic DDL. (Minus a *secure margin* in case the newest row(s) get deleted / deactivated - if that can happen)
- Invoke this secondary function at off-times with a minimum of concurrent activity per cronjob or on demand. As often as you want, can't do harm, it just needs a short exclusive lock on the table.

Here is a **complete working demo**.
@erikcw, you'll have to activate the commented part as instructed below.

```
CREATE TABLE report_rank(created timestamp);
INSERT INTO report_rank VALUES ('2011-11-11 11:11'),(now());

-- initial function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_report_rank_cap()
  RETURNS timestamp LANGUAGE sql COST 1 IMMUTABLE AS
$y$SELECT timestamp '-infinity'$y$;  -- or as high as you can safely bet.

-- initial index; 1st run indexes whole tbl if starting with '-infinity'
CREATE INDEX report_rank_recent_idx ON report_rank (created DESC NULLS LAST)
WHERE  created > f_report_rank_cap();

-- function to update function & reindex
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_report_rank_set_cap()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _secure_margin CONSTANT interval := interval '1 day';  -- adjust to your case
   _cap timestamp;  -- exclude older rows than this from partial index
BEGIN
   SELECT max(created) - _secure_margin
   FROM   report_rank
   WHERE  created > f_report_rank_cap() + _secure_margin
   /*  not needed for the demo; @erikcw needs to activate this
   AND    EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM   report_site    s
     JOIN   report_profile p ON p.site_id = s.id
     JOIN   crm_client     c ON c.id      = p.client_id
     JOIN   auth_user      u ON u.id      = c.user_id
     WHERE  s.id = r.site_id
     AND    u.is_active
     AND    c.is_deleted = FALSE)
   */
   INTO   _cap;

   IF FOUND THEN
     -- recreate function
     EXECUTE format('
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_report_rank_cap()
       RETURNS timestamp LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE AS
     $y$SELECT %L::timestamp$y$', _cap);

     -- reindex
     REINDEX INDEX report_rank_recent_idx;
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_report_rank_set_cap()
IS 'Dynamically recreate function f_report_rank_cap()
    and reindex partial index on report_rank.';
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_report_rank_set_cap();
```

See:

```
SELECT f_report_rank_cap();
```

Uncomment the clause `AND r.created > f_report_rank_cap()` in the query above and observe the difference. Verify that the index gets used with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

[The manual on concurrency and `REINDEX`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-reindex.html):

> To build the index without interfering with production you should drop the index and reissue the `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` command.

Comment: I don't think this is strictly equivalent but it's definitely more readable!

Comment: You are both right of course, it was a work in progress. @wilplasser, maybe you can hold your horses, the edit confused me quite a bit. Don't be so quick to edit an answer while the author might still be at it.

Comment: here comes the CTE ... Sorry, won't happen again. I just cant stand horizontal scrolling (it were only some lousy dependant expressions, but you have to scroll to find _that_ out ...)

Comment: @wildplasser: Yeah, I am not a fan of that pesky horizontal scroll bar either. Chances are I clean that up, before I close case.

Comment: @wildplasser: you may be interested in the "ultimate speed" part I added to my answer. :)

Comment: CTE - ? Continuing Technical Education ? Classical Text Editor ? oh I get it, Critical Technology Element ;)

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Commonly Tolerated Exaggeration. :) OK, [seriously](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/queries-with.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
-- modelled after Erwin's version
-- does the x query really return only one row?

SELECT r.id, r.keyword_id, r.site_id
    , r.rank, r.url, r.competition, r.source
    , r.country, r.created, x.max_created
-- UPDATE3: I forgot one, too
FROM report_rank r
LEFT   JOIN report_site s  ON (r.site_id = s.id) 
JOIN   report_profile   p  ON (s.id = p.site_id) 
JOIN   crm_client       c  ON (p.client_id = c.id) 
JOIN   auth_user        u  ON (c.user_id = u.id)
-- UPDATE2: t7 has left the building
WHERE  u.is_active
AND    c.is_deleted = FALSE
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM report_rank x
       -- WHERE 1=1 -- uncorrelated subquery ??
       -- UPDATE1: no it's not. Erwin seems to have forgotten the t7 join
       WHERE r.id = x.site_id
       AND x.created > r.created
       ) 
;
```

Comment: This is better I think. The joins to `u` and `c` should go inside the subquery, too, I think.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the equivalence of Erwin's version (or mine) with the original one. To the OP: please reduce your query to a readable version.

Comment: You would need to repeat the WHERE conditions in the subquery. (I had that wrong in my first draft, too.) Else, if the latest entry is deleted or inactive, no rows will be returned. Other than that, `NOT EXISTS ( .. x>r)` is a nifty trick.

Comment: I'm quitting. Best way in that case would probably be to condense all meat into a CTE and perform a self-join on that. The max() trick is still valid, though (NOT exists WHERE_bigger outperforms max() in a subquery, most of the time) Anyway: I'm  out of here. Oh, and yes: I basically  parasited on your rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

### Alternative interpretation

I was busy optimizing the query you presented and missed a piece of what you wrote:

> I'm trying to retrieve the latest report_rank for each report_profile.

Which is **something different entirely** to what your query is trying to do.

**First**, let me demonstrate how I distilled the query from what you posted.
I removed the `""` and noise words, used aliases and trimmed the format, arriving at this:

```
SELECT r.id, r.keyword_id, r.site_id, r.rank, r.url, r.competition
      ,r.source, r.country, r.created
      ,MAX(t7.created) AS max 
FROM   report_rank      r
LEFT   JOIN report_site s  ON (s.id      = r.site_id) 
JOIN   report_profile   p  ON (p.site_id = s.id) 
JOIN   crm_client       c  ON (c.id      = p.client_id) 
JOIN   auth_user        u  ON (u.id      = c.user_id) 
LEFT   JOIN report_rank t7 ON (t.site_id = s.id) 
WHERE  u.is_active
AND    c.is_deleted = False
GROUP  BY
       r.id
      ,r.keyword_id
      ,r.site_id
      ,r.rank
      ,r.url, r.competition
      ,r.source
      ,r.country
      ,r.created 
HAVING MAX(t7.created) =  r.created;
```

- What you are trying to do with `T7` and `HAVING` cannot work on principal, I pruned that.
- `LEFT JOIN` will be forced to a plain `JOIN` in both cases. I substituted accordingly.
- From your query I deduced that `report_site` is in a 1:n relationship to both `report_rank` and `report_profile`, and that's how those two are linked. Therefore, `report_profile` that belong to the same `report_site` share the same latest `report_rank`. You might as well group by `report_site`. But I sticked to the question asked.
- I eliminated `report_site` from the query. It's irrelevant, as long as it *exists*, which I assert.
- Since PostgreSQL 9.1 it's enough to `GROUP BY` the primary key per table. I simplified accordingly.
- For simplification I selected all columns of `report_rank`

With all that, I arrived at this **basic query**:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM   report_rank    r
JOIN   report_profile p USING (site_id) 
JOIN   crm_client     c ON (c.id = p.client_id) 
JOIN   auth_user      u ON (u.id = c.user_id) 
WHERE  u.is_active
AND    c.is_deleted = FALSE
GROUP  BY r.id;
```

Building on this, I created a solution with the ...

#### Latest `report_rank` for each `report_profile`

```
WITH p AS (
    SELECT p.id AS profile_id
          ,p.site_id
    FROM   report_profile p
    WHERE  EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM   crm_client c
        JOIN   auth_user  u ON u.id = c.user_id
        WHERE  c.id = p.client_id
        AND    c.is_deleted = FALSE
        AND    u.is_active
        )
    ) x AS (
    SELECT p.profile_id
          ,r.*
    FROM   p
    JOIN   report_rank r USING (site_id)
    )
SELECT *
FROM   x
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   x r
    WHERE  r.profile_id = x.profile_id
    AND    r.created > x.created
    );
```

- I assume there is a `report_profile.id` though you did not mention it.
- In the 1st CTE I get a unique SET of valid profiles.
- In the 2nd CTE I join with  `report_rank` to produce the resulting rows
- In the final query I eliminate all but the latest `report_rank` per `report_profile`
- Can be one or more row, if `created` is not unique.
- The solution with the partial index in my other answer is not applicable with this variant.

Finally, advice for performance optimization from the PostgreSQL wiki:

- [Tune the server settings](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server), be sure to allocate a lot of memory in the right place.
- Check your [hardware](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Database_Hardware).