# Add an index to a timestamp with time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, count, timezone

I want to improve this slow query, I thinking to add an index, but I don't know what index type is better to my case.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) ct FROM events
WHERE dtt AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'
   >= date(now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago') + interval '1s'
```

Query Plan:

```
"Aggregate  (cost=128032.03..128032.04 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=3929.083..3929.083 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..125937.68 rows=837742 width=0) (actual time=113.080..3926.972 rows=25849 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (timezone('America/Santiago'::text, dtt) >= (date(timezone('America/Santiago'::text, now())) + '00:00:01'::interval))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 2487386"
"Planning time: 0.179 ms"
"Execution time: 3929.136 ms"
```

- The query gets the count of events of the day.
- dtt is a timestamp with time zone column.
- I'm using Postgresql 9.4.

Note:
With the Erwin advices the query run a little faster but still I think isn't fast enough.

```
"Aggregate  (cost=119667.76..119667.77 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=3687.151..3687.152 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on vehicle_events  (cost=0.00..119667.14 rows=250 width=0) (actual time=104.635..3687.068 rows=469 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (dtt >= timezone('America/Santiago'::text, date_trunc('day'::text, timezone('America/Santiago'::text, now()))))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 2513337"
"Planning time: 0.164 ms"
"Execution time: 3687.204 ms"
```

Comment: Nitpicking, your query does ***not*** "get the count of events of the day". It gets the count of *all* events since the beginning of the day - including future timestamps if there are some, which might easily happen with multiple time zones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, fix your query to make the predicate ["sargable"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable):

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   events
WHERE  dtt >= date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago')
                                      AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago';
```

Use the column value as is and move all calculations to the parameter.

That's right, after truncating to the local start of the day, apply [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) a second time to convert the `timestamp` value back to `timestamptz` again. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

#### Explanation step-by-step

1. **`now()`**
   .. is the Postgres implementation for the SQL standard `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Both are 100 % equivalent, you can use either. It returns the current point in time as **`timestamptz`** - the *display* of the value takes the time zone of the current session into consideration, but that's irrelevant for the *value*.
2. `now()` **`AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'`**
   .. computes the local time for the given time zone. The resulting data type is **`timestamp`**. We do this to allow for:
3. **`date_trunc(`** `now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'` **`)`**
   ..  truncates the time component to get the local start of the day in 'America/Santiago', independent of the current time zone setting.
4. `date_trunc('day', now() AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago')` **`AT TIME ZONE 'America/Santiago'`**
   .. feeding the `timestamp` to the `AT TIME ZONE` construct we get the corresponding **`timestamptz`** value (UTC internally) to compare the `timestamptz` value `dtt` to.

I removed the `+ interval '1s'`, suspecting you have just been abusing that to convert the `date` to `timestamp`. Use `date_trunc()` instead to produce a `timestamp` value.

Now, a **plain (default) btree index on `dtt`** will do. Of course, the index will only be used, if the predicate is selective enough.

```
CREATE INDEX events_dtt_idx ON events (dtt);
```

If your important queries only consider recent rows, a **partial index** might help some more. Details:

- [Get latest child per parent from big table - query is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087861/very-slow-postgresql-query/8088075#8088075)

Comment: Thanks Erwin for your answer, I have now a better result, but the query still is slow, is needed do a reindex to my table?

Comment: @Goku: `REINDEX` is only necessary if the index is terribly bloated or corrupt. `VACUUM  ANALYZE events` might help to give you an [index-only scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans). If you can't get index-only scans due to too much writing activity, clustering the table might make it faster. [Details here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998139/optimize-postgres-timestamp-query-range/14007963#14007963)

Comment: Did you forget to convert back to UTC?  Or does that happen implicitly in the comparison?

Comment: @Matt: Neither. "Converting to UTC" is an implicit detail of converting to `timestamptz` - which is a UTC timestamp internally and works independent of time zones. Don't be confused by the somewhat misleading data type name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28876266/939860. Follow the links for details.

Comment: Ok, so `date_trunc` still returns a `timestamptz`. It's truncated to the start of the local date of the specified time zone, but it still internally tracks the UTC point in time - correct?   Does the truncation properly deal with time zones that skip over midnight on a DST transition day?  (Example, `America/Sao_Paulo` started the day at 1:00 AM on Oct 19, 2014.)

Comment: @MattJohnson: No. `date_trunc()` returns `timestamp` for `timestamp` input and `timestamptz` for `timestamptz`. I added an explanation step-by-step to clarify.

Comment: Moving the `AT TIME ZONE` part from the column to the parameter improved the time of my query from 11 seconds to 4 ms(!). Thank you for your answer!